# Gaussian approximation to arbitrary distribution in Kullback–Leibler divergence

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, information-theory, entropy

The Kullback–Leibler divergence of two densities $p_1,p_2$ over $\mathbb R^d$ is$\def\KL{\mathrm{KL}}$
$$  D_\KL(p_1,p_2)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1(x) \log\frac{p_1 (x)} { p_2(x)}\,\mathrm d x.$$
I know from Gibbs' inequality that $D_{\KL}$ is non-negative. Now I want to prove the following: let $p_2$ be a fixed density, and $p_1$ the density of some Gaussian distribution, then $D_{\KL}(p_1,p_2)$ is minimized exactly when $p_1$ takes the expectation of $p_2$ as its expectation, and the covariance matrix of $p_2$ its covariance matrix.

I guess this might require a very technical proof.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?

Comment: This is not right. And the TA told us that what is to be minimized is not $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(p_1,p_2)$ but $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(p_2,p_1)$. And this is reduced to an inequality on cross entropy.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your conjecture is false. Let $p_2$ be a centered [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) with unit variance.

Then if $p_1$ is a Gaussian with zero mean and variance $s$, then the distance  $D_{KL}(p_1,p_2)$ is *not* minimized at $s=1$.

[image]